# How to give a scoring's based on an input word

Tags: python, python-3.x

Shown below is the syntax used to give a score for a user based on the letters from a user input word,

```
letter_with_score = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5,'f':6,'g':7,'h':8,'i':9,'j':10,
                         'k':11,'l':12,'m':13,'n':14,'o':15,'p':16,'q':17,'r':18,'s':19,'t':20,
                         'u':21,'v':22,'w':23,'x':24,'y':25,'z':26, ' ':0}
    

while True: 
    user = input("Enter a word: ").lower()
    print()
    
    user_word_split = []
    score = []


    for i in user:
        user_word_split.append(i)
    

    for k, v in letter_with_score.items(): 
        if k in user_word_split: 
            score.append(v)
        
    print()
    print(sum(score))
    print()
```

However, for an example if a user inputs a word such as "*Hello*", the user will get a score of 40. Where the actual score should be 52.

How can this be resolved to get the actual score.

Answer (score 3):

Try this oneliner using `map` on user input with mapping function `dict.get`:

```
while True: 
    user = input("Enter a word: ").lower()
    score = sum(map(lambda l: letter_with_score.get(l, 0), user))
    print(score)
```

Output

```
Enter the word: hello
52
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're iterating the dictionary. Let's take a case `hello`
h e l l o
8 5 12 12 15

When you check `l` twice and get `12` twice and try to append in the `score` list. But having `12` already in the `score` list it's overriding the first 12 that's why you're getting `sum(score)` is 40

```
while True:
    user = input("Enter a word: ").lower()
    score = []
    for i in user:
        if i in letter_with_score.keys():
            score.append(letter_with_score[i])
    print()
    print(sum(score))
    print()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `letter_with_score` is a dictionary, so you can get the score for each letter by indexing that dictionary with `[]`. Thus you can construct a list of the scores for each letter in the input word (not just the unique letters) and sum over that list to get the total score:

```py
letter_with_score = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5,'f':6,'g':7,'h':8,'i':9,'j':10,
                     'k':11,'l':12,'m':13,'n':14,'o':15,'p':16,'q':17,'r':18,'s':19,'t':20,
                     'u':21,'v':22,'w':23,'x':24,'y':25,'z':26, ' ':0}
    
user = input("Enter a word: ").lower()

scores = [letter_with_score[letter] for letter in user]
print(sum(scores))
```

Note that you can iterate over a string directly, so there is no need to split the input word into letters first.

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of taking all the values from a to z in a dictionary , I have a better approach for you**

You can simply use asci value of the character using **ord()**

try the following code it will be simple and easily understandable

```
T=input()
T=T.lower()
total=0
for i in range(len(T)):
    if T[i]==" ":
        total=total+0
    else:
        total=total+int(ord(T[i])-96)
print(total)
```